# Подсчет параметров у нейронной сети

Tags: машинное-обучение

Прохожу курс по машинному обучению.
В разделе на нейронные сети (в тесте) просят посчитать количество параметров у нейронной сети, если нам известно:

- количество входных признаков
- количество нейронов в скрытом слое
- количество нейронов в выходном слое.

Не могли бы вы мне подсказать, где можно взять необходимую литературу, где описан процесс расчета данных параметров или формулу для расчета?

Comment: Параметры нейронной сети — это набор весов (*weights*) у каждого нейрона и их *biases* (у каждого нейрона — один bias). Количество весов складывается с количеством biases и получается количество параметров.

Comment: @eanmos  Я правильно понял, что если весов 3, а нейронов в скрытом слое 4, и в выходном слои один нейрон, то ответ будет 16?

Comment: Количество весов нейронов в скрытом слое будет равно 3 × 4 = 12 (количество входных значений умножаем на количество нейронов в скрытом слое. Количество весов в выходном слое будет равно 4. В сумме — 16 весов. Прибавляем к этому количество biases во всей сети: так как у каждого нейрона по одному bias, а нейронов всего 5 (4 в скрытом и 1 в выходном), то всего biases 5 штук. 16 весов плюс 5 biases = 21. Ответ — 21.

Comment: Кажется, был уже подобный вопрос тут где-то, не могу сейчас что-то найти.

Answer (score 1):

Формула для расчета количества обучаемых параметров модели:

```
sum([p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad])
```